# How to jump to previous instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
.globl main
main:
    movl     $4,     %eax
    dec     %eax
    jnz    ... # jump back to the previous instruction if not zero
    ret
```

If not, what would be the proper way to do something like the above? I suppose the corresponding C would be something like:

```
int main() {
    char a = 4;
    while (a-- != 0);
}
```

Here is what I've come up with so far, but not sure if this is the proper way to do it or how it could be improved (for example, why do sections usually start with a dot, such as `.L1` ?):

```
.globl main
main:
    movl     $4,     %eax
DECREMENT:
    dec     %eax
    jnz     DECREMENT
    ret
```

Comment: Beware that your assembly code doesn’t match the C code, because it doesn’t do the post-decrement properly.

Comment: @prl what would be a more accurate representation of it?

Comment: At the end of the C function, a is -1, not 0.

Comment: It's hard to say what an accurate representation of it would be, because the code shown is dead code, so a compiler will remove it entirely. Depending on what you add to make it not dead, the code may change entirely. For example, if you return `a` at the end of the function, it compiles to "return -1" (with no loop at all). If you call a function inside the loop, the compiler might unroll the loop and just put in four calls to the function. If you want to see a number of variations, I recommend you experiment at godbolt.org.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's *exactly* what labels are for. You can just introduce a new label and use that as a target for the `jnz` instruction:

```
.globl main
main:
    movl    $4, %eax
prev:
    dec     %eax
    jnz     prev
    ret
```

Keep in mind that this creates `prev` as a file-wide label, meaning it must be unique in the entire source file. Some assemblers also cater for numeric labels which *can* be duplicated. When you use them, it finds the closest one in the direction specified:

```
.globl main
main:
    movl    $4, %eax
1:
    dec     %eax
    jnz     1b        ; closest '1', going backwards (b).
    ret
```

This is a very handy feature that allows you to do "localised" labels without polluting the label namespace, and avoids having to use long labels like `main_loop_1`. The suffix for the numeric label indicates the direction to go looking for the label, `b` is backwards, `f` is forwards.

Comment: Nope, `prev` is not a global label here (would need `.globl prev` to make it one.  It only needs to be unique within the file.

Comment: @fuz, I meant global as in "it has to be unique in the whole file" as opposed to the localised ones, but I can see I've raisded confusion with the `.globl` specifier - I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a label:

```
.globl main
main:
    movl     $4,     %eax
loop:
    dec     %eax
    jnz     loop
    ret
```

Comment: cool what I got was pretty similar so looks like I am on the right track! Is there a convention for how to name a label? I often see things like `.L1`

Comment: @David542: yes, `.L` labels are local to the file, not visible in the symbol table at all, even as debug symbols (so they won't make a debugger think it's a new function), see the GAS manual.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/.  Then the rest of the label name is just autonumbered by the compiler (sometimes with gaps, probably numbering is based on an index in its internal data structures.)  Human authors should prefer at least somewhat meaningful names.  (Careful with ones like `loop` that are also valid x86 instruction mnemonics.)

Comment: @David542: There are some existing SO Q&As with answers that explain some of this.  IDK if there's one good one with a coherent overview, but I'd suggest looking.